# Validate Sudoku on a Mobius Strip

Tags: code-golf, decision-problem, grid, sudoku

[@BeastlyGerbil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70004/beastly-gerbil) presents, the world's very first **MOBIUS SUDOKU**:

> [image: Picture of the original strip.]

---

[image: Screenshot of the strip in Google Sheets.]

[Google Sheets version](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ZAQKFn0pnUyejh7S44mqpeSgYC_YTtOkIcJcciJfbjM/edit?usp=sharing)

(The left most square backs onto the right most square, and the middle squares back onto each other. The ends are then attached as indicated.)

**RULES**:

- Normal sudoku rules apply for rows and boxes - boxes are split into groups of 3 indicated by the thicker lines.

  - This means that each row must contain the numbers 1 - 9 without repetition.
- Columns ‘wrap around’ over the edge of the mobius strip – 6 cells per column as a result, normal sudoku rules apply on these 6 cells.
- No number will ever be orthogonally adjacent to itself, including across the thicker borders separating the sets of 3 boxes.
- There are 18 total boxes, and as a result 18 total middle cells. There are 2 of each number, 1-9, in the middle cells.

<sub>***Note**: If you need additional information or references for "normal" sudoku, [here](https://www.sudokuonline.io/tips/sudoku-rules) is a great resource.*</sub>

---

##### Input

Your input will be a collection of integers in \$[1,9]\$, representing each side of a completed strip respectively. Here, *collection* means whatever type of collection works to meet your needs, so long as you accept a value for every square (front and back). You can use comma delimited lists, arrays, arrays of arrays, n-dimensional arrays, lists, etc. For example in C# using a comma delimited list:

> 4,6,1,8,5,3,7,9,2,4,8,1,3,9,7,6,5,2,6,4,2,8,1,9,5,3,7,2,7,8,4,9,1,6,5,3,6,7,5,1,4,2,9,3,8,3,8,9,7,2,5,6,1,4,9,5,3,6,2,7,4,1,8,2,9,3,5,8,6,7,1,4,5,7,1,4,6,3,9,8,2,1,9,4,2,8,5,6,3,7,1,9,2,5,7,4,6,3,8,5,7,2,9,8,1,4,3,6,5,6,2,7,3,9,8,1,4,7,6,8,3,2,9,4,5,1,6,8,1,5,4,3,2,9,7,3,7,8,1,4,6,5,9,2,3,4,5,1,6,8,9,2,7,4,3,9,6,7,2,5,8,1

***Note**: You must tell us how to input the data.*

##### Output

Your output should represent whether or not the provided input is a valid solution using your languages truthy/falsy, with respect to [this answer](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2194/81972):

> ```
> if (x) {
>    print "x is truthy";
> }
> else {
>     print "x is falsy";
> }
> ```
>
> If it results in a runtime or a compile-time error then x is neither truthy nor falsy.

For example in C#, when provided the above input, the expected output is:

> true

##### ✔️ Test Cases

Your test inputs will represent both valid and invalid solutions to include the original puzzle's solution:

> **Test Case 1**: 0
> **Test Case 2**: 4,6,1,8,5,3,7,9,2,4,8,1,3,9,7,6,5,2,6,4,2,8,1,9,5,3,7,2,7,8,4,9,1,6,5,3,6,7,5,1,4,2,9,3,8,3,8,9,7,2,5,6,1,4,9,5,3,6,2,7,4,1,8,2,9,3,5,8,6,7,1,4,5,7,1,4,6,3,9,8,2,1,9,4,2,8,5,6,3,7,1,9,2,5,7,4,6,3,8,5,7,2,9,8,1,4,3,6,5,6,2,7,3,9,8,1,4,7,6,8,3,2,9,4,5,1,6,8,1,5,4,3,2,9,7,3,7,8,1,4,6,5,9,2,3,4,5,1,6,8,9,2,7,4,3,9,6,7,2,5,8,1
> **Test Case 3**: 8,8,8,8,8,8,7,9,2,4,8,1,3,9,7,6,5,2,6,4,2,8,1,9,5,3,7,2,7,8,4,9,1,6,5,3,6,7,5,1,4,2,9,3,8,3,8,9,7,2,5,6,1,4,9,5,3,6,2,7,4,1,8,2,9,3,5,8,6,7,1,4,5,7,1,4,6,3,9,8,2,1,9,4,2,8,5,6,3,7,1,9,2,5,7,4,6,3,8,5,7,2,9,8,1,4,3,6,5,6,2,7,3,9,8,1,4,7,6,8,3,2,9,4,5,1,6,8,1,5,4,3,2,9,7,3,7,8,1,4,6,5,9,2,3,4,5,1,6,8,9,2,7,4,3,9,6,7,2,5,8,1

Your outputs should be (again, in C# for example):

> **Test Case 1**: false
> **Test Case 2**: true
> **Test Case 3**: false

Here's a screenshot of the solved grid for reference:
[image: Screenshot of the solved grid.]

##### Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so smallest solution in bytes wins.

##### Final Note

This challenge is inspired by [this puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/111725/sudoku-on-a-mobius-strip) crafted by [@BeastlyGerbil](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/70004/beastly-gerbil). If you like this challenge, go show some love for the original puzzle too!

Comment: You might want to clarify what is meant by "rows" in "Normal sudoku rules apply for rows", since it is not immediately apparent.

Comment: @WheatWizard added a nested bullet and a subscript note containing a link to "normal" sudoku rules. Does that help?

Comment: That's good but my actual concern was what "row" meant.  Here it seems to mean nine cells between two extra thick bars, whereas is common speech it usually just means any horizontal line of cells.

Comment: We need a challenge for solving Mobius strip sudoku puzzles!

Comment: Could you add some more truthy test cases, as well as some test cases which are correct for the 3x3 blocks; 1x9 'rows' and 6x1 Mobius columns, but incorrect for one of the two two rules: i.e. two of the same adjacent numbers with a thick border between them; or where the 18 middle cells aren't containing the 1-9 numbers twice each.

Comment: "6 cells per column as a result, normal sudoku rules apply on these 6 cells." can you elaborate on this since 'normal sudoku rules' in my mind require 9 cells?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 44 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly)

```
s€3;"3/Ẏ;;ZFs9ƲQ€ƑȧZṙ3;"Ɗ;"`IƲȦȧḊm3FƊ⁺ĠƊṁ€Ƒ2
```

A monadic Link that accepts a list of twenty-seven length six lists of integers that yields `1` if valid or `0` if not.

The input is a list of the twenty-seven columns starting with one adjacent to a bold border and reading around the strip, where each column reads in the same order as every other such that it starts at one edge of the Mobius-strip then reads one side followed by the other with wrapping (at the other edge of the Mobius-strip).

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TZEtbgMxEIWvYgVbqvy3trU8UmFpViuVlEQpCipM4IJIhWVFDQkKSoIra6@xuYhjz4zXYfY3fvOeZ9Yfm81XjNv7/qTahXqZboe2XS23PpzfEgvf43E1XX9SLQzt4v01nMe/8Thdhk@1DMN9d/v/DcN03cFbGWPsOs2Z5MxzJjiznDU9Z10DR8OZg4rKTMBNAU4CnVkCSd4ASBWRmQGJhA6p6DJTc3eQ@8zwpou1zMxDWUCz1NtmJssNnUxms6mF146y2GJtamYDco/ymmX@myZfDYC6Uj4JAOMYmot/Go2k/2JLDOUpMwZWGJG0dXjkgaa2zECR1j9FbOrfyICyiJIPbVyd3zztkg9Vru4NX7iykrIPXRaZl9D3Dw)**

#### How?

It's a long chain so I'll break it down...

```
s€3;"3/Ẏ;;ZFs9ƲQ€Ƒ - are all nonets, columns, and rows distinct sets?: columns
s€3                - split each column into threes
     3/            - three-wise reduce by:
   ;"              -   zipped concatenation
       Ẏ           - tighten -> the eighteen nonets
        ;          - concatenate with the twenty-seven columns
              Ʋ    - last four links as a monad, f(columns):
          Z        -   transpose
           F       -   flatten
             9     -   nine
            s      -   split (flatten result) into slices of lenth (9)
                     -> the eighteen rows
         ;         - (nonets & columns) concatenate (rows)
               Q€Ƒ - is invariant under deduplicate-each?
                     -> 1 if all nonets, columns, and rows are distinct sets
                          else 0

ȧZṙ3;"Ɗ;"`IƲȦ - ...and there are no adjacent cells which are equal?
                   (note that the distinct sets check performed earlier automatically
                    checked rows & columns. Rows get checked again here as it is golfier)
           Ʋ  - last four links as a monad, f(columns):
 Z            -   transpose -> the six half-Mobius-strip-rows on the "front" and "back"
      Ɗ       -   last three links as a monad, f(half-Mobius-strip-rows):
   3          -     three
  ṙ           -     rotate (half-Mobius-strip-rows) left by (3)
    ;"        -     zipped concatenation -> full-Mobius-strip-rows
       ;"`    -   zipped concatenation with itself (to cater for row-wise wrapping)
          I   -   incremental differences ([b-a, c-b, ...] for each)
ȧ             - (current check result) logial AND (that)
            Ȧ - non-empty and contains no 0 when flattened?
                -> 1 if all nonets, columns, and rows are distinct sets
                        AND no adjacent cells are equal
                     else 0

ȧḊm3FƊ⁺ĠƊ - ...if so get the middles of all nonets grouped by values, otherwise 0
        Ɗ - last three links as a monad, f(columns):
     Ɗ    -   last three links as a monad, g(columns):
 Ḋ        -     dequeue
  m3      -     modulo-3 slice
    F     -     flatten
      ⁺   -   repeat -> g(that result) -> middles of all nonets
       Ġ  -   group indices by value
ȧ         - (current check result) logial AND (that)
            -> those groups if all nonets, columns, and rows are distinct sets
                               AND no adjacent cells are equal
                             else 0

ṁ€Ƒ2 - ...and the groups (or the 0 we have instead) are all length 2?
  Ƒ  - is invariant under:
ṁ€ 2 -   mould each like [1,2]
       -> 1 if a valid fill of an empty Mobius-strip-Sudoku
            else 0
```

Answer (score 11):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>54</s> 47 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
3δôø˜©‚˜9ôI2ä`í«ø«D€ÙQIÂí‚øε˜Ć}D€ÔQ®9ô€Ås9L¢<PP
```

Takes the input as a 6x27 matrix, kinda like the reference screenshot of the grid.
Outputs `1` for truthy, or another integer (usually `0`) as falsey.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##TU@xSgQxEP2haS7J5DZgaXNgcVcvCypYWFlcLciBfoGNspXYyHlWK2ydsVu4j7gfWd9MglgkmXl5b96bu@3V9e3NPPvjIIOMU58/Tg@vU59kWDl5v5RD3suY9@en3ae8bFaykwMIMh6/p/7n6d7w503@gkDLx226yG9n6/U8t22gSAtqiMnTkhI5CugW6BL6CNzhDrgVTYXXUevw2wBPQKOhEQijU25C39jRKQ64ugToUuWqPphzYTMqnaB6rm@0FGBAp94lBRu@tDTOuIXZWO1MoWq4QMfVy//hupVmczaRLb/@sGkU1f287VdSsDn5f@xU8@vUWDcEu@t@AQ) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##7VKxSsRAEP2VcPUUd5vs3i4I11xpcVcvARUsrCwOhBSCHHgfIDZKKrGR86wipM7aBe4j8iPxzWxQCyttjyWbmbfvzZtZ9nJ1enZx3l8Vs1HSbe6S0ayY9@m@ClWo27J56W4e29KFqlDh@STsmm2om@28W7@Gh2UR1mEHQqj37235sbkW/H7ZvEHA4e3KHTdPR4tFT733fpznlHifkaEJWdKU0pQcKcqQTZA55Aa4wp5hZ9RFXk5e4dQCd0CNoAaIRsZch9zKx1UUcHbJoHMDl/WZOEe2RsQVWK@Hv5EuwICOvWMXWvCpdKOEG5lWYiUKVsMFOj14pV84T8W9KamopX8@0aJhlOdLZb7YhRan9AfbDf1zVTNMCHa80jH9YcHyoPtNJ1dq6XsdXum/X2n@CQ).

**Explanation:**

Step 1: Transform the input-matrix to a (flattened) list of blocks:

```python
 δ          # Map over each row of the (implicit) input-matrix
3 ô         #  Split the inner list into parts of size 3
   ø        # Zip/transpose this matrix; swapping rows/columns
    ˜       # Flatten it
     ©      # Store this list in variable `®` (without popping)
```

Step 2: Pair it with the flattened input and split both the 'rows' and blocks into parts of size 9:

```python
      ‚     # Pair it together with the (implicit) input-matrix
       ˜    # Flatten it to a list of integers
        9ô  # Split it into parts of size 9
```

Step 3: Get all Mobius columns, and merge those to the same list:

```python
I           # Push the input-matrix again
 2ä         # Split it into 2 equal-sized parts
   `        # Pop and push both separated to the stack
    í       # Reverse each inner list of the second matrix
     «      # Merge the two lists back together again
      ø     # Zip/transpose this matrix; swapping rows/columns
       «    # Merge it to the earlier list of nonets
            # (We now have a list of all 'rows'; all blocks; and all Mobius columns)
```

Step 4: Check for each 'row', block, and Mobius column that they only contain unique digits:

```python
D           # Duplicate the list of lists
 €Ù         # Uniquify each inner list
   Q        # Check that it's still equal to the list of lists
```

Step 5: Connect the Mobius rows as shown by the colors in the challenge description, including wrap-around:

```python
I           # Push the input-matrix again
 Â          # Bifurcate it, short for Duplicate & Reverse copy
  í         # Reverse each inner row of this reversed copy as well
   ‚        # Pair it with the input-matrix
    ø       # Zip/transpose; creating pairs of the rows of the two matrices
     ε      # Map over the pair of lists:
      ˜     #  Flatten it to a single connected row
       Ć    #  Enclose it, appending its own first item
     }      # Close the map
```

Step 6: Check that these connected Mobius rows doesn't contain any adjacent pair of digits that are the same:

```python
      D     # Duplicate it
       €Ô   # Connected-uniquify each inner list in this duplicate
         Q  # Check if both matrices are still the same
```

Step 7: Check if the center cells of each block all combined contain each positive digit twice:

```python
®           # Push the list of variable `®`
 9ô         # Split it into parts of size 9 to get a list of blocks
   €Ås      # Only leave the center cell value for each block-list
      9L¢   # Count for each value in [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9] how many time it occurs in
            # this list of block center cells
         <  # Decrease each by 1
          P # Take the product of this list (1 if all counts were 2;
            # another integer (0, negative, or positive) if a count wasn't 2)
```

Step 8: Check if everything combined is truthy, and output the result:

```python
P           # Check if the three are truthy by taking the product on the stack
            # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this for a step-by-step of the input to the output.](https://tio.run/##bVRNb9NAEL3zK1a9tJXcQ5zYxAjUQytQJaoWceAQRcrG2SRLN950d90QTqgS/AJOqCcEB9SPU4V6jo@V@BH9I2Fm1k6atlLiZMdvZt57M7a2vCvFfL62l41z94Ktbb@a/d1@tvZGOOaGgnWVTo8s0306SQRtKWkd2@gr7pzIRG@TbTGurGbWaSMAJy0A2Qk3kneVYJ3ZVQcL1/9dF9fFze3Z7I/vccilYRL66EfF8bxu9MSub7JFIyxy9@XH7ZlPfz9WkIyfDCqMuXHE08rPgiWITYrrVTH7uitzy1Kt8lH2SBSp3wuLX53icnZe3PjcfWEG4h5LwY2SwjDiyS2bCKUwcXbu8TtDkR6xvjaATIfggsqxBeOsVQuS9pbh2UD0fPpkKKAkerBOlnk2WVndkoa34NrvFcGodjkWkluPA@RnCfC0UsLFrG/0iC3dZTzrPSxG3t2dfqvc84qkN8vmI0JypVabsBRhlnFYgRgrdA7id2UBI7gTlJ5qkJc6MKBMRhargxhxZ@QnmkVxWlzCwIubu9OLauo7iwp5Jo9z2Z8@ZdsuZBTfH/Anm62TQF0c51ytLB7bsHQC@hO8ZJrx3keeisyVaBqlXY52qQVEbGLXUu9hbocru0IG@80m/1ceDcYHXGYBTcKurDRPHfZdjiepOGB/WrqrxY4fZGrKlOAn3uiR7PWgQQrbiZlEeEnDT/ii@GorU3OQOdQTNuIZGCpHZZNqNGNtpZNQuycHEp@zNM2N38/ZT19jV6QwZysqc7Bid8pqiHrpIR8MH9PmlLui/cpbx2FATg/Kp4G0wy5mA1BQ0d30JV77lwF45B1Lq@GKE2Gm8O7JBgzeP87kbjgN4AmTQAYCOjfMCJsrKnZ7dhjM561WI4iDWtAMoqAePA@SIAwacKrBKYFzDPEQrg24YjTxuHbQCuFuE@IJRGOKxhCJ4ITYBM5N@mKVEOLYpQF5SYnF/AZ19ugI/mEFzI/K35hYAALysLdnEVH8ObEJCeuRTfofUgZmQxfIi8pe9UUcVSG3kCpGxB/vRJSDUdRXJ32eRUSd6vfQSckfq8alQkC32/8B)

Comment: Are "No number will ever be orthogonally adjacent to itself, including across the thicker borders separating the sets of 3 boxes." and "There are 18 total boxes, and as a result 18 total middle cells. There are 2 of each number, 1-9, in the middle cells." somehow redundant or does this check them in some way I haven't noticed?

Comment: @JonathanAllan Should be fixed now. I've also asked OP for some additional test cases.

Comment: Your connected uniquify check neglects the cells that become adjacent when the strip is connected into a loop.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Ugh.. Fixed again, thanks.

Comment: You're now only checking half of those connections - your "connected Mobius rows of the input-matrix" would need the first digit appended to the end of each (or have each be repeated if golfier).

Comment: Note that the input is now restricted to containing integers in \$[1,9]\$ which should save you some bytes I imagine (saved me 7 of 51).

Comment: @JonathanAllan Lucky we have the `Ć` builtin (append own head) for that. :) And restricting it to `[1,9]` doesn't save any bytes in my approach. I have used a similar approach as your `Q€Ƒ` now to save bytes instead, although I'm not 100% sure if this is correct for all possible inputs. The challenge doesn't seem to guarantee that the input always contains the correct size / amount of values, so isn't there some kind of input where this could be incorrectly truthy even though digits are missing? Or will those always fail for the other checks in that case?

Comment: I read "Here, collection means whatever type of collection works to meet your needs, so long as you accept a value for every square (front and back)." as not needing to validate dimensions (maybe there is a meta consensus - seems like it should be a default that we do not need to validate the input); if so my `Q€Ƒ` is fine, but I can't comment on your equivalent however.